# Android Touch Bounding Rectangle and Texture Location

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, bounding-box

Just using the coord system my `rectangle` for my touch bounding box never seems to align with the coordinated and placement of my textures.

What is the simplest way to draw bounding box `rectangles` so that I can line them up with my drawn `textures`?

Im using OPEN-GLES

EG..

```
playBounds = new Rectangle( 240, 400, 157, 177);
batcher.drawSprite(240, 400, 157, 177, Assets.mainMenu);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that because the bounding rectangles are based on the lower left corner and texture coords are based on the center, the below seems to be the best solution.

```
playBounds = new Rectangle(240, 400, 157, 177);
batcher.drawSprite(
    playBounds.lowerLeft.x + playBounds.width / 2,
    playBounds.lowerLeft.y + playBounds.height / 2, 
    playBounds.width, 
    playBounds.height, 
    Assets.mainMenu
);
```